# Cant start uwsgi in ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, django, wsgi, uwsgi

When I run  "/etc/init.d/uwsgi start" nothing happens, the terminal just gives me a new line and no output. There is no sign of uswsgi in ps aux  as well and /var/log/uwsgi.log is empty

I'm folowing this instructions:

http://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/python-uwsgi/ubuntu-10.10-maverick

Answer (score 0):

I find it best to debug uwsgi from the command line. Use the xml file format which can be helpful or the .ini file format if you prefer. You will also need a stack that supports a WSGI handler of some type for your application. For django and example would be:

/home/project/django_wsgi.py:

```
import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

/home/project/uwsgi.xml:

```
<uwsgi> 
    <module>django_wsgi</module>
    <http>127.0.0.1:8080</http>
    <pythonpath>/home/project</pythonpath>
    <master/>
    <max-requests>5000</max-requests>
</uwsgi>
```

Then test it:

matt@mcp:~$ uwsgi -x /home/project/uwsgi.xml

You will need a recent version of uwsgi for this to work .96+..

Hope this helps.